# DataReader google finance date not working

Tags: python, google-finance, pandas-datareader

I was just using pandas datareader to get the stock data for the past two weeks or so and it was working fine.  All of a sudden since yesterday the date provided wasnt working anymore.  It just gives me the past year data and I cant change the date.  Used to work with the one commented out, but now its not.  I even changed it to use datetime object, but still not working.  Any idea?  I updated pandas and pandas_datareader still no luck.  Used another computer still didnt work.  Did they just recently change the API?

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

#start = '2010-01-01'
#end = '2017-7-31'
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,7, 31)
f = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'google', start, end)
print(f.head())
```

output:

```
              Open    High     Low   Close    Volume
Date                                                
2016-09-19  115.19  116.18  113.25  113.58  47023046
2016-09-20  113.05  114.12  112.51  113.57  34514269
2016-09-21  113.85  113.99  112.44  113.55  36003185
2016-09-22  114.35  114.94  114.00  114.62  31073984
2016-09-23  114.42  114.79  111.55  112.71  52481151
```

Comment: This is a common problem. Either a bug with datareader, or the repositories do not provide this data anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Google has changed the Google Finance URL to finance.google.com/finance/historical rather than www.google.com/finance/historical, which is used as the URL in the pandas_datareader.

Server returns HTTP 302 when fetching data from the old URL and redirect to the new URL. However, the parameters startdate/enddate are missing during the HTTP redirection.

The url is set in the source code:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/google/daily.py

Maybe you can modify the URL and use your own version of pandas_datareader.

Answer (score 1):

The url has now been updated, so upgrading datareader will fix the problem:

`sudo pip install pandas_datareader --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

According to data reader docs, Yahoo!, Google Options, Google Quotes and EDGAR have been immediately deprecated due to large changes in their API and no stable replacement. Use 'iex' instead

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt    

start = dt.datetime(2018,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)

aapl = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'iex', start, end)

aapl.shape
(251, 5)

aapl.head()

    open    high    low close   volume
date                    
2018-01-02  167.6431    169.7514    166.7564    169.7120    25555934
2018-01-03  169.9780    171.9682    169.4165    169.6825    29517899
2018-01-04  169.9879    170.9041    169.5347    170.4707    22434597
2018-01-05  170.8746    172.7760    170.4904    172.4115    23660018
2018-01-08  171.7711    173.0125    171.3573    171.7711    20567766
```